# How to configure JFrog Artifactory with MySQL?

Tags: artifactory, derby, jfrog-cli

I'm upgrading Artifactory from v4.0 to v5.3 in a Linux server (*Oracle Linux Server v8.4*) and I'm doing the **Zip installation**. I've done all the configurations required for MySQL (maria db),

- configuring storage.properties (/etc)
- configuring default (/etc)
- configrung configure.mysql.sh (/bin)

Apart from the above steps I've copies mysql.properties (/misc/db) to /etc and renamed it to db.properties and tried to start Artifactory. When I try to start it like this it gives me below error.

```
WARNING: The web application [artifactory] registered the JDBC driver [org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Jun 16, 2023 3:49:42 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesJdbc

WARNING: The web application [artifactory] appears to have started a thread named [Thread-4] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.nio.fs.LinuxWatchService.poll(Native Method)
 sun.nio.fs.LinuxWatchService.access$600(LinuxWatchService.java:47)
 sun.nio.fs.LinuxWatchService$Poller.run(LinuxWatchService.java:314)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Like the above warnings more warnings were received with the same info about thread failing to stop and creating a memory leak.

Due to this error, I just deleted the db.properties (/etc) file which I have copied from /misc and tried to start the Artifactory and then it started fine without any error. And after starting I checked /etc and a db.properties file was automatically created when starting the artifactory and that file includes details as below pointing to derby.

```
type=derby
url=jdbc:derby:{db.home};create=true
driver=org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver

#binary.provider.type=filesystem

#binary.provider.cache.maxSize=5GB[artifactoryv5@localhost etc]$
```

So when I import the DB dump from web ui it won't be imported to the MySQL db I created.

How to fix this issue ?
(If I configure the db.properties files after this start it still give me the same error of thread and memory leak)

Furthermore, in the Artifactory web documentation there's a mentioning about changing the config using `system.yaml` file in the path *$JFROG_HOME/artifactory/var/etc/artifactory* , but there's no /var directory in the zip file and couldn't find any file named *`system.yaml`*

Comment: Are you certain these messages are causing you a problem? The messages are only *warnings*

Comment: These warnings were received when the db.properties file was modified. So the root cause of the warnings lies within changing the db.properties file, which stops Artifactory from starting.